# Replace the word in the list with the value from the dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of words

```
words = ['apple', 'peach', 'tomato']
```

And a dictionary

```
translations = {'apple':' apfel', 'banana': 'banane', 'peach': 'pfirsich', 'orange': 'apfelsine'}
```

I need to find all the words that match the keys in the dictionary and replace the missing ones with something like `<none>` and put it all into a new list. That is, the result should be as follows:

```
result = ['apfel', 'pfirsich', '<none>']
```

The list and the dictionary can have more than 10,000 items if it is important.

Comment: `result = [translations.get(k, '<none>') for k in words]`.  However, don't use `list` and `dict` as variable names as they will shadow the original built-ins of the same name.

Comment: what did you try? share the code please.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this:

```
words = ['apple','peach','tomato']
translations = {'apple':'apfel','banana':'banane','peach':'pfirsich','orange':'apfelsine'}
    
result = [translations.get(i, '<none>') for i in words]
#['apfel', 'pfirsich', '<none>']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['apple', 'peach', 'tomato']

translations = {'apple':' apfel', 'banana': 'banane', 'peach': 'pfirsich', 'orange': 'apfelsine'}
```

One way you could do this is just iterating through with the .items() method which returns your dictionary as containing the key-value pairs of the dictionary, but as tuples in a list.

This way you are able to iterate through and treat it like a list
For example:

```
result = []
#k,v refers to our key-value pairs in our dictionary
for k,v in translations.items():
    # checks if key is in our list
    if k in words:
        # appends the value onto the list
        result.append(v)
    else:
        # appends alternative value
        result.append("<none>")
print(result)
```

Alternatively and my personal favorite as it's able to be re-used is to put it into a definition..

```
#lst is the list, dct is the dictionary
def multi_dict(lst, dct):
    result = []
    for k,v in dct.items():
        if k in words:
        # appends the value onto the list
            result.append(v)
        else:
        # appends alternative value
            result.append("<none>")
    return result

print(multi_dict(words, translations))
```

Either way it should allow you to iterate through 10,000 items or more.